# Is there a way to check if a postback is in progress?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the case that a button is clicked multiple times on a page - Is there a way to figure out using javascript/jquery that a postback is already in progress and cancels the new attempt to submit the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid users from double clicking by disabling whatever form elements can cause a form submit.

Checkout http://greatwebguy.com/programming/dom/prevent-double-submit-with-jquery/ for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the button on first click, so that you could not click it when the post is in progress, and re enable it when the post-back has finished.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
   var submitted = false;  
   function SubmitTheForm() {
     if(submitted == true) { return; }
     document.myform.submit();
     document.myform.mybutton.value = 'Thank You!';
     document.myform.mybutton.disabled = true;
      submitted = true;
    }
 </script>
<form method="post" action="#">
<input type="submit" onclick=return SubmitTheForm()>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could always just disable the button in the onclick handler.

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var self = this;
   $(self).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   $.post('url',$(self).closest('form').serialize(), function() {
      $(self).removeAttr('disabled'); // re-enable after request complete. 
   });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could have your click event set a variable in your click handler to true and only allow the handler to proceed when the value is false. Of course you will have to set it to false again when your callback finishes.

```
if (!processInProgress) {
  processInProgress = 1
  // start the process
}
```